How to get an image from the clipboard in Blazor hybrid?
I tried many things, but at the end I made it with javascript.
I wonder however if there is a method without using javascript?
Dot Net MAUI has a Clipboard class but only for text, why?
Maybe someone has some ideas on the topic?
Thank you
